# ENVI Error running FLAASH Atmosphere Correction

Tags: envi, flaash

I've made a Radiometric calibration on a Landsat-8 image.
Next, I've tried to make a FLAASH Atmosphere Correction from the Toolbox but I get a warning message and the process stops with errors.

The warning indicates that for western hemisphere the longitude should be negative and in fact, the Landsat-8 image I am processing has a positive longitude.

The warning message is:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

The Input parameters I use for the FLAASH Atmosphere Correction are:

[image]

For the Multispectral settings I've used:

[image]

and...

[image]

and the finnal error message:

[image]

Comment: Which Envi version do you have? Before 5.2 Landsat 8 is not support 100%. Why not to use Landsat Higher Level product? It is in surface reflectance

Comment: Thank you. I am using ENVI+IDL 5.1. What do you mean with Higher Level Product in surface reflectance? You're referring taking a different approach for the atmosphere correction?

Comment: I mean [products with atmospheric correction](https://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat-surface-reflectance-high-level-data-products). You can order them from EarthExplorer or ESPA for free

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.
Instead of inserting the Scene Center Location (DATE_ACQUIRED for date and  SCENE_CENTER_TIME for time), I was using the FILE_DATE information from the metadata file. Changed the values to meet the correct ones and problem solved.

Anyway, the best solution is to order Landsat Higher Level products as per also_tapia sugestion.